# Scene Kit View with moving Object

Tags: swift, scenekit, .obj

How can I show a moving 3D object in my Simple view Application using scene kit view with swift 4.

For example bee.glb file in windows, I am using these four files:

1. body.bmp
2. body.jpg
3. volkeswagon-vw-beetle.mtl
4. volkeswagon-vw-beetle.obj

   ```
   import UIKit
   import SceneKit
   import ARKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()


   // 1: Load .obj file
   let scene = SCNScene(named: "volkeswagon-vw-beetle.obj")

   // 2: Add camera node
   let cameraNode = SCNNode()
   cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
   // 3: Place camera
   cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 35)
   // 4: Set camera on scene
   scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

   // 5: Adding light to scene
   let lightNode = SCNNode()
   lightNode.light = SCNLight()
   lightNode.light?.type = .omni
   lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 35)
   scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

   // 6: Creating and adding ambien light to scene
   let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
   ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
   ambientLightNode.light?.type = .ambient
   ambientLightNode.light?.color = UIColor.darkGray
   scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

   // Allow user to manipulate camera
   sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

   // Show FPS logs and timming
    sceneView.showsStatistics = true

   // Set background color
   sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

   // Allow user translate image
   sceneView.cameraControlConfiguration.allowsTranslation = false

   // Set scene settings
   sceneView.scene = scene
   }

   }
   ```

The output is:

> "3DVideo[6430:105708] [SceneKit] Error: Physically based lighting model is not supported by the OpenGL renderer, using Phong instead (3)
>   2019-09-02 03:29:13.297536-0700 3DVideo[6430:105708] [SceneKit] Error: Physically based lighting model is not supported by the OpenGL renderer, using Phong instead (2)
>   2019-09-02 03:29:13.308381-0700 3DVideo[6430:105708] [SceneKit] Error: Physically based lighting model is not supported by the OpenGL renderer, using Phong instead"

Comment: This is only a guess and since no one has answered, I saw this post that I "think" is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374054/scenekit-view-renders-as-phong-instead-of-physically-based-materials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve this issue  by Just change my file extension from .obj to .dae.Because obj file has no any animation